# Rifle across the back

Tags: minifigures

I'd like to build a hunter minifig with a [rifle](https://store.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30141#T=C) slung diagonally across his back.

I thought about using the [dual katanas armor](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98132&name=Minifigure,%20Armor%20Shoulder%20Pads%20with%20Scabbard%20for%20Two%20Katanas&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Body%20Wear%5D#T=C)  but it looks like it would only fit a flat blade, right?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Also, what would be a good torso for an outdoors/forest/hunter type?

Comment: It might be better to split your question into two questions - one about the rifle attachment, and one about suitable torsos.

Comment: A quick search for [LEGO ranger torso](https://www.google.com/search?q=LEGO+ranger+torso&tbm=isch) gives a good starting point or for more "camo" styles, the [LEGO Endor Trooper](https://www.google.com/search?q=LEGO+endor+trooper&tbm=isch) might be better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use

Minifigure, Neck Bracket with Back Stud

[28974](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=28974#T=C) thick /  [42446](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=42446#T=C)thin

With
Tile, Modified 1 x 1 with Clip

[15712](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15712#T=C) / [2555](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2555#T=C)

[image]